# How to set TimeZone in android for a particular date and time?

Tags: android, datetime, calendar, timezone

I developed an application , in that i need to save the the event date and time. By default the time and date are in "America/Chicago" timezone format. Now, i need to convert them into user's device Time Zone format. but i got wrong format.

I did the following.

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater1=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy-hh:mm a");//10-23-2012-08:30 am

curFormater1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago")); 

curFormater1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

**current output:** 
   TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago") is  10-22-2012-10:00 PM
   TimeZone.getDefault() is   10-23-2012-08:30 AM

**Required output**
    TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago") is  10-23-2012-08:30 AM
     TimeZone.getDefault() is   10-23-2012-07:00 PM

Comment: i want 10-23-2012-8:30 am as "America/chicago" timezone format.but, it treated as default timezone.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same trouble but found a way out.
TimeZone sets to the device's timeZone by default. To change this and to set it to a specific timeZone use the getRawOffset() property.
This method calculates the milliseconds from the current time. So you can add the milliseconds for your specified timeZone and subtract those for the default timeZone.

When I tried to change it to timeZone 'GMT_ID'

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startDate.getTime()  +TimeZone.getTimeZone(GMT_ID).getRawOffset() -TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples

[Convert time between timezone](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Converttimebetweentimezone.htm)

[Converting Times Between Time Zones](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/GetTimeOtherZone2.html)

```
      import java.util.Calendar;
       import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
       import java.util.TimeZone;

  public class TimeZoneExample {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a calendar object and set it time based on the local
    // time zone

    Calendar localTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    localTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
    localTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    localTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

    int hour = localTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = localTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = localTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);


    // Print the local time

    System.out.printf("Local time  : %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);


    // Create a calendar object for representing a Germany time zone. Then we
    // wet the time of the calendar with the value of the local time

    Calendar germanyTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Germany"));
    germanyTime.setTimeInMillis(localTime.getTimeInMillis());
    hour = germanyTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minute = germanyTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    second = germanyTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);


    // Print the local time in Germany time zone

    System.out.printf("Germany time: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);
}
}
```